# BeforeLeaveObserver is not invoked after page reload in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I have a problem:
`BeforeLeaveObserver` is not invoked after `ui.getPage().reload();`
I need to reload view after the user change the application language, so this action is invoked after the user change and save. Then the view is translated to another language dynamically.
After that another functionality which is using BeforeLeaveObserver is not invoked.
Any ideas how to make observer work again? Or maybe there is another way which will work?

I was trying with `LocaleChangeObserver` a had a trouble to refresh layout and translate it - it's too complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only rely on `BeforeLeaveObserver` for situations when the user navigates from one view to another in the same UI. Reloading the page causes a new UI to be created which means that `BeforeLeaveObserver` isn't triggered. The old UI instance is still there with the old view active.

The framework could in theory detect the situation specifically for a reload that is triggered from code but it's not trivially detectable when the user reloads through the web browser. It would be just as confusing if different types of reloading would lead to different outcomes.

For you case, you might want to instead redirect the user to a URL that contains a parameter that you can use to identify the custom configuration that the new UI is supposed to adopt.